# Where should I ask a comeback to the OP about the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions, accepted-answer

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615157/android-is-there-any-way-to-iterate-a-path-object) I stumbled upon.

The question can be viewed as a polar question ("is there any way to") and the answer can be summarized as "yes" (there is a way to).

The answer also contains a clue on how this solution could be achieved, without giving much details.

Obviously the user who answered is not willing to go into the details about a possible implementation, but I would like to know more, plus the Asker did accept the answer, so maybe he did follow the advice and ended up with a good solution.

I was thinking about leaving a question for the Asker in a comment with @ mention, but I can't decide if I should leave the comment in the OP or in the accepted answer.

Is it acceptable to ask the Asker for a comeback on a solution he might have developed based on an advice contained in the accepted answer, and if so, where should I ask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to leave a comment on the question/answer, although there's no guarantee you'll get a reply (especially since the question is several years old).

You could also:

- [Add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to the question, and write a custom message detailing what extra information you'd like to see in the answers.
- If your specific case is unique enough, ask a separate question and reference the other question in yours.
- If your question is very similar except for a few minor details that you can't seem to figure out, you can still probably ask a separate question, but [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) could also be a way to get help. (Post the question in chat, and then explain the few places where you'd like additional help.)

Comment: The question is exactly what I'm looking for and I don't see any other on the topic, it might be too specific if nobody else asked in four years. I'll try to solve it by myself a bit longer and I'll add a bounty to the question if I don't succeed. Thank you.